# Call a function with empty argument

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script, which is called `master.cmd`. It accepts `6` arguments.

I want to call a function in this script, for example, the name of the function is `plopsl_tka`.

In this function, I see this check:

```
if [%6]==[] ( echo no need to update
```

It means that if the last parameter is null, print this message.

From my script - lets call it `dba.cmd`, I want to call to this function `plopsl_tka` *(from master.cmd script)*, and I want to call it with `null` argument.

This is what I did *(this is my script: dba.cmd)*:

```
if [!client!]==[Ct] ( call c:\autoprocess\master.cmd plopsl_tka pk sdeploy1ry_pl_env14 ctrdr cy_pd_env18 !rel_version! ' ')
```

As you can see, the last & sixth argument is `' '`; this is how I thought to call a function with `null` argument, but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: `' '` is not "null", it's a space character. If you want "null", provide nothing.

Comment: You should get in the habit of using double quotes for your string comparison as well as when passing arguments to another batch file.  Your `IF` commands that expand variables will fail if the value of the variable has a space in it. The accepted best practice for the majority of us to do this: `if "!client!"=="" echo blah`. This will protect spaces and special characters in the values of your variables.

Comment: It appears from the example that seven (7) parameters are being passed on the `master.cmd` command line.

Comment: If you really want to pass an empty variable to a batch file, I would advise you use this syntax. `foo.bat "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" ""`.  Then you would test for it like this: `IF "%~6"=="" echo No Sixth argument`